# How to overcome MYSQL views union slow response on "Limit"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 views in MYSQL with the same number of columns and same types. These 2 views aggregate data from different sources but they actually refer to the same data so I want to make an union on them to do some pagination, sorting etc.

The problem is, once I do this I cannot limit results fast because MYSQL doesn't support materialized views.

How can I overcome this without complicating myself?

LE.

The data changes frequently. I have 12k entries in the first view and ~4k entries in the second view. Most of the second view is more like a subset of the first view.

I cannot dump mysql and I do not have any control over the views...

Comment: you can easily replicate materialized views by doing `create table foo as <your query>` and then query foo

Comment: idd, I need more like a materialized view incrementally updated when either of the views is updated and that's such a hassle for me to handle ...

Comment: 1. Create a table with your query result columns, 2. Create a trigger on the source table with delete and insert created table in step 1.

Comment: That means I should have a trigger for each source (2) and doing this complete refresh is very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

How frequently those results changes? And how many are there?

If it changes rarely you can cache the result in the application layer.

Without knowing specifics, nothing else comes to my mind.

Comment: ....even if it changes frequently, it's easy to added triggers to capture this and update the cache

Comment: I would like not to do any merging, caching in the app layer because to do that would imply pulling all the data from both views in the memory and that would defy the purpose of pagination.

Comment: why do you want to perform queries each time you need pagination? if queries are slow you don't want to fire them for pagination, most likely